# res folder not loading from .aar library in AOSP

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android.mk

I am working on an AOSP project where I need to use a .aar library with the res folder.
I have added .aar reference in Android.mk file but getting below error while opening the app.

**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field activity of type I in class Lcom/sample/voice/R$layout;**

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES += voice

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages com.sample.voice

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += voice:libs/voice.aar
```

Tried many solutions but don't know how to include the res file in the Android.mk.
But this is working in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in Android.mk to include the .aar/res folder in the .apk.

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR +=$(call intermediates-dir-for,JAVA_LIBRARIES,<voice>,,common)/aar/res
```

Here `<voice>` is your library name.